# When to use De Moivre/Laplace and when to use the Central Limit Theory to calculate probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

As the number of attempts of a binomial distribution approaches infinity, it approximates to a Normal distribution with $\mu= np $ and $\sigma= np(1-p)$.

My question is: When do you use each one? I seem to be getting confused as to whether I should be using

$$\Pr(X\lt x)= \Pr\left(Z\lt \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right) \text{ or } \Pr\left(Z\lt \frac{x-\mu n}{\sqrt{n}\cdot\sigma}\right)$$

Comment: When using the normal distribution to approximate the normal distribution, you should use a continuity correction if $n$ is not very large.  If $X$ is an integer-valued random variable, then the event $X\le12$ is the same as the event $X<13$, and the continuity correction consists of finding $\Pr(X < 12.5)$ when $X$ has the continuous approximate distribution. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first of all, DeMoivre-Laplace is the special case of the central limit theorem for the binomial distribution. You don't really need to remember it as a separate result.

Secondly, the point is to do a shift and rescaling so that your random variable has mean zero and variance $1$. For a sum of independent identically distributed random variables, that winds up being $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - n\mu}{\sqrt{n} \sigma}$. To rewrite this in terms of the sample mean, you divide top and bottom of that by $n$ to get $\frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$. The binomial distribution is a sum of independent Bernoulli random variables, so if you are estimating a binomial probability you would want the first form.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to use a normal approximation to a binomial distribution if it's too difficult to compute the probability using the binomial distribution.
What constitutes "too difficult" depends on what computational resources you have available.  With a computer and good mathematical software, calculating binomial probabilities for $n$ in the thousands is no problem at all.

Comment: During an exam I'm limited to quite a basic scientific calculator. Although being able to use a computer and some software during exams would definitely be great!

Comment: It's also decent for quick estimates using the 68-95-99.7 rule. For instance, if I flip a fair coin 100 times, about 68% of the time it will be between 45 and 55 heads, about 95% of the time it will be between 40 and 60 heads, and it will almost always be between 35 and 65 heads.

Comment: Note that in this case with $n=100$ (big but not huge), "about" is actually not so great; my first estimate is off by ~4%, the second is off by ~1.5%, and the third is off by ~0.1%. But still, it gives the rough scaling behavior for deviations from the mean in units of standard deviations when adding up relatively large samples. In particular it tells you that things cluster around the mean *much* more than the *a priori* estimate (Markov's inequality) would imply.